# Upgrading from mvc4 to mvc5 with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, nuget, asp.net-mvc-5

I made the switch to upgrade and updated the proper nuget packages, set up entries in my web.config, etc, but there is an issue in my Views and apparently is being caused by two versions of mvc still on the machine 4 & 5.

When I manage the nuget package for my project, it says to restart visual studio so it can uninstall it (which it doesn't). It also said I could find more info on it in my activitylog.xml file, of which I don't have when searching my whole drive.

The question is, how can I **manually uninstall** the following from my machine?
**Microsoft.AspNet.MVC.4.0.20710.0**

Below, is the content of my packages.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CodeContracts.Unofficial" version="1.0.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DataAnnotationsExtensions" version="1.1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DataAnnotationsExtensions.MVC3" version="1.1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" version="4.0.3.12153" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Glimpse" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Glimpse.Ado" version="1.7.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Glimpse.EF6" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Glimpse.MiniProfiler" version="1.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.7.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MiniProfiler" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Twitter.Helper" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Below, is the content of my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings configSource="Configs\Prod\connectionStrings.config" />
  <appSettings configSource="Configs\Prod\appSettings.config" />
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Admin" />
      <allow roles="AdminStage" />
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="60" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="720" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    <trust level="Full"></trust>
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="data Source=s07.winhost.com;database=DB_36079_yeagertech;user id=DB_36079_yeagertech_user;password=Bellay58" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />
    <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework45" validationKey="C63E672C62DC06F295AAACD40F41A0340F37C5D28477FA01D90DEAFBE90E163BDF56ECF72DFD9B09D89B3A1E080DCD82712F87B5A7E328EB3AB2F79572F65F2D" decryptionKey="837239C11FF36D980633F216C2AD9CD977527B15D631803712B4DFD3891606F0" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
                <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
                </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="PostSharp" publicKeyToken="b13fd38b8f9c99d7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.32.9" newVersion="3.0.32.9" />
      </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.Data" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.WebData" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="~/yeagerte/YeagerTechWcfService.YeagerTechWcfService.svc" service="YeagerTechWcfService" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IYeagerTechWcfService" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IYeagerTechWcfService1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logEntireMessage="true" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2147483647" maxMessagesToLog="500" />
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services configSource="Configs\Prod\system.serviceModel.services.config" />
    <client configSource="Configs\Prod\system.serviceModel.client.config" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="postmaster@yeagertech.com">
        <network host="m05.internetmailserver.net" password="Bellay58" userName="postmaster@yeagertech.com" port="587" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

I left the connectionstrings and system.servicemodel config files out because they shouldn't be casuing this.

My appsettings.config file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
  <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="Env" value="Prod"/>
  <add key="Domain" value="yeagertech.com"/>
  <add key="UserName" value="yeagerte"/>
  <add key="Password" value="Bellay58"/>
  <add key="microsoft.visualstudio.teamsystems.aspnetdevserver:/" value="4514;True;15712;1;-8588719243754423046" />
  <add key="microsoft.visualstudio.teamsystems.backupinfo" value="1;web.config.backup.16312425-023f-49eb-a968-4e0afc4a422a" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: I had the same problem as well. It's not so much related to a migration from MVC4 to MVC5 as it is a TFS problem. I think your comment means you solved it though right?

Comment: Correct, thanks for listening...

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> When I checked in my items, and re-launched visual studio, I got the following msg in the output window: The item `C:\Users\byeager\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\YeagerTechSolution\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20710.0` could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.
>
> I believe **this has been solved** after doing the above checkin....